# Why in my JS popup my html form doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

I make a popup which says "are you sure you want to delete the category?" If they say yes, exec a form but this form doesn't work?

The html code:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("popup");
var btns = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".remove_openpopup"));
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close_button")[0];
btns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
});
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
span2.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#" class="remove_openpopup">remove</a>
  <a href="#" class="remove_openpopup">remove2</a>
  <a href="#" class="remove_openpopup">remove3</a>

  <div id="popup" class="popup">
    <div class="popup_content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Are you sure you wan't delete this categorie ?</p>
      <button class="button_popup close_button">No</button>
      <button class="button_popup close_button" onclick='document.getElementByClassName("remove").submit()'>Yes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="remove" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="remove" /></form>
</body>
```

The test script:

```
if (isset($_POST['remove'])) {
  echo "a";
}
```

When I click yes nothing happen.
Someone have an idea?

Comment: Nothing happens? Don't you get an error in the JavaScript console saying that `document.getElementByClassName` is not a function?

Comment: You do keep the console open when you're debugging JS, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using getElementByClassName but it doesn't exist. The closest thing is getElementsByClassName, which returns an array of elements with the requested class name, but in this case I think you should use getElementById and set the id property to your form:

```
<body>
    <a href="#" class="remove_openpopup">remove</a>
    <a href="#" class="remove_openpopup">remove2</a>
    <a href="#" class="remove_openpopup">remove3</a>

    <div id="popup" class="popup">
      <div class="popup_content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Are you sure you wan't delete this categorie ?</p>
        <button class="button_popup close_button">No</button>
        <button class="button_popup close_button" onclick='document.getElementById("remove").submit()'>Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form id="remove" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="remove" /></form>
</body>
```